# Listing the most popular 8 city (custom fields) as used in posts

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-fields

Hi there i am creating a theme for a classifieds website and want to list the top 8 popular city which mentioned as posts custom fields. That means the top 8 cities which have the most classifieds. it will looks like this

http://i50.tinypic.com/6f7fww.png

i saw some examples of sorting custom fields but couldn't manage to make it work properly.

Comment: So you have a meta field, and its value is a city? Or is the meta field value sometimes many cities (in a comma separated list for example)?

Comment: custom_field is city and city can be any cities (e.g. London, Manchester etc.) and if there is 3 londons, 2 liverpools and 1 manchester London will be the first than liverpool than manchester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do this with WPDB and SQL:

```
global $wpdb;
$cities = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'city'
GROUP BY meta_value 
ORDER BY c DESC" );
```

Replace city with the actual meta key. $cities will be an array that is ordered by number of posts that has the city in its corresponding meta field.

To print this array, $cities, you can use for example this code:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $cities as $city ) {
    echo '<li>' . $city . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: the meta_key is actually 'city' which can contain different cities (london,liverpool,manchester etc.) so if the london most used one it should be the first city on the list.

Comment: OK, what happens when you test it?

Comment: to be honest i've never used wpdb queries before. i tried something but the only result i had was 'array'. if you can also help me ..

Comment: Put that code in functions.php and then after that `print_r( $cities ); exit;` just to see if it works. If it does, you should see a list of cities.

Comment: i did put those codes in functions and when i put print_r( $cities ); exit; on the page whatever below this is gone. if i remove exit; i have full page loaded but with no result on the list

Comment: Exactly, so what I wanted to know was if the list was OK? I need to confirm we're getting the result you expect from the database.

Comment: the list box was empty. no result came up

Comment: It should have said array( ) (or something like it) if it was empty. I'm sorry but it's hard to help you, here are the things I would like to do to make this work: Open PHPMyAdmin and run the SQL query directly on the database, first of all, then if that works check the documentation for all the functions involved. At that point you should know why this isn't working but I can't do it for you (it's not so simple to help via comments like this). You have to try to debug this, or wait for someone else to post a solution.

Comment: i got this error when use the code above : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You would have to create an archive based on meta values. That warrants a question of its own.

Comment: I am able to get result now thanks alot :) just one more thing how can i link them to the page which contains those posts which have that meta_key. I mean is there any way to have a link like domain.com/?meta_key=london.    i have     echo '<li> <a href=/wordpress/' . $city . '>' . $city .  '</li>'; so far ..

Answer (score -1):

Do this :

```
            <?php

              $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
              // Retrieves your custom fields
              $my_city_custom_field = $custom_fields['city'];
              // Retrieve all values for your "city" custom field
              foreach ( $my_city_custom_field as $key => $value )
                $cities[$value]=$city[$value]+1;
                // add one to the city index of the cities table
                // So first time London comes up you get 1, second time 2, etc.

                asort($cities);
                // sorts the $cities table by value

               foreach ( $cities as $key => $value )
                echo($key);
                // print the city's names, in proper order

            ?>
```

I might have done this a bit fast, but at least, you will get the idea

Comment: Thanks for your reply whatever the Calle told me worked great but i am having problems to link those tags to category.php. i need to create a path like domain.com/custom_field/london .. I read lots of articles and tutorials and saw about taxonomies but still couldnt link them to taxonomy.php . in full of headache